# Ubuntu Server NON system HDD transfer rate

Tags: networking, server, samba

I am using samba for file sharing, but transfer rates are very strange.

When I am moving files to a NON system HDD, the transfer rate is ~25MB/s.
But when moving files to the HDD, where my system is installed, transfer rate is ~60MB/s (Max speed of the HDD)

It seems off that non-system HDDs are performing better than the system HDD.

Is there any reason for this, e.g. caching to the system drive and than copying to the non-system drive?

Comment: Network transfer rates are always slower than direct-to-disk transfers - its not caching or anything it's always just "faster" with physically connected drives vs. over a network share

Comment: Yes, overhead of TCP proto and Samba, but both of those speeds are network transfers ... I have two network shares One is on drive with system second share is on separate drive. network transfer to the separate drive shares has 2-3times slower transfer times ... I switch HDDs, reinstalled system, but problem was still there, again transfer to the sys drive was 2-3times faster than non-sys (hope this is understandable :) )

Comment: I accidently **found answer** to my question ... Problem was the filesystem of the second drive. Looks like linux doesnt like NTFS very much. I reformated to the EXT4 and all is OK now ... Can copy with max drive speed :)

Comment: @AlexNeumer Please post the preceding comment as an answer to your own question and you can also accept your own answer after you wait 48 hours from when the original question was posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally found the answer to my question. The problem was the filesystem of the second drive. Looks like Linux doesnt like NTFS very much. I reformated to EXT4 and all is OK now ... Can copy with max drive speed :)